# Spatialite find the nearest node for the given lat/lon

Tags: mysql, sqlite, spatialite

I am struggle on this for a few days, I am not sure why the query was wrong..
I want to find the nearest point at the given lat/lon.

```
SELECT rid,DISTANCE(geometry, MakePoint(-79.91759, 43.266571))
FROM room2f ORDER BY DISTANCE(Startpoint(geometry), MakePoint(-79.91759, 43.266571))limit 1
```

It's always return the first row, nomatter what point I use. Then I tried to remove "limit1":

```
SELECT rid,DISTANCE(geometry, MakePoint(-79.91759, 43.266571))
   FROM room2f ORDER BY DISTANCE(Startpoint(geometry), MakePoint(-79.91759, 43.266571))
```

The result is very strange... The result is sorted by rid rather than distance, I think this is why it always return the first row. Is my query wrong? Or, there is a bug in Spatialite?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NAO6.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the `.dump` from SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database as something of a [mcve]?

Comment: You are not using `StartPoint` in both distance calculations. But this indeed looks like a bug.

Comment: What does `SELECT rid, AsEWKT(Startpoint(geometry)), AsEWKT(geometry) LIMIT 5` show? Can you add that to the question?

Answer (score 0):

In your sql statement you compare to different distances..

1. From your geometry in general to your specific point (as I know it is the shortest distance from the point to your geometry).
2. From the first point of your geometry to your specific point.

Therefore you also get a different ordering of your result!

See the reference to the distance function:
http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html#p13